# How do I disable Google Instant Previews?

Tags: google-search

Is there an official way to disable the Google Instant Previews feature?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to permanently disable the feature at present but for now it isn't working in encrypted Google (https://www.google.com) so can be avoided.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to work for non-us sites.

Answer (score 1):

http://thenextweb.com/lifehacks/2010/11/16/how-to-disable-instant-previews-in-google-search/

Firefox:

1. Download [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/), install and restart browser
2. Snag the necessary script from [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/90659.user.js)
3. Install the script then do a Google search
4. Click the Disable Instant Previews link in the top right

Chrome:

No need to install Greasemonkey as Chrome supports scripts natively

1. Grab the same script as the Firefox users from [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/90659.user.js)
2. Click “Continue” when you see the security warning
3. Do a Google search, then Disable Instant Previews with the top right link

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, since I already have a hackish solution in place, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Missed the 'official way' part of your question, I'll try and fully read it next time :)

Answer (score 0):

FF users don’t need any add-ons or scripts to disable this.

Nor do they need to change their homepage.

In FF you can disable instant search and instant previews by modifying the about:config file.

Instructions here-

http://www.ehow.com/how_7190054_disable-instant-search-permanently-firefox.html

Simple and it worked for me with no (as yet) apparent problems.

Thanks, E-How!

Comment: Cool, I only wish there was a similar solution for Safari!

Answer (score 0):

No need - Google Instant [is no more](https://www.theverge.com/2017/7/26/16034844/google-kills-off-instant-search-for-mobile-consistency).

I take it you were not referring to [this](https://developers.google.com/vr/tools/instant-preview).